# broadcast data to multiple clients on the same machine with the lowest lag

Tags: c#, broadcast, udpclient

Server and multiple clients are on the same machine. I want my server to send data to clients with minimal latency. I want my server to act like a radio station. (it will be streaming data from financial exchanges,but for now it is just streaming the time.)

-it doesn't matter if a few packages are lost, I don’t want those to be resent

-server should not care if clients are still busy consuming the previous data

-it is fine if server is broadcasting even if no one is listening

I do not know much about sockets and ports. Is there an already existing solution for my problem in C#?
I have tried named pipes but in that case server can serve only one client.
This is what I have tried so far. I am hoping that someone with more expertise could direct me to a better solution.

```
class Program
{
    static string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    static int port = 32123;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpServer server = new UdpServer(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port));
        server.OnIncoming += Server_OnIncoming;

        UdpListener client = new UdpListener(ip, port);
        client.OnIncoming += Client_OnIncoming;

        UdpListener client2 = new UdpListener(ip, port);
        client.OnIncoming += Client2_OnIncoming;

        UdpListener client3 = new UdpListener(ip, port);
        client.OnIncoming += Client3_OnIncoming;

        UdpListener client4 = new UdpListener(ip, port);
        client.OnIncoming += Client4_OnIncoming;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                server.Broadcast(DateTime.Now.MyString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Client_OnIncoming(object? sender, string message)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeSpan =now- DateTime.Parse(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Client1 latencyms:{timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}");
    }
    private static void Client2_OnIncoming(object? sender, string message)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = now - DateTime.Parse(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Client2 latencyms:{timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}");
    }

    private static void Client3_OnIncoming(object? sender, string message)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = now - DateTime.Parse(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Client3 latency_ms:{timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}");
    }
    private static void Client4_OnIncoming(object? sender, string message)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeSpan = now - DateTime.Parse(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Client4 latency_ms:{timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void Server_OnIncoming(object? sender, string e) => Console.WriteLine($"Server incoming message:{e}");
}


class UdpServer
{
    UdpClient Client;
    private IPEndPoint _listenOn;
    public event EventHandler<string> OnIncoming;
    ConcurrentBag<IPEndPoint> listeners=new ConcurrentBag<IPEndPoint>();

    public UdpServer(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        _listenOn = endpoint;
        Client = new UdpClient(_listenOn);
        StartListening();
        OnIncoming += UdpServer_OnIncoming;
    }

    private void UdpServer_OnIncoming(object? sender, string e)
    {
        var subscriber = (IPEndPoint)sender;
        if (listeners.Contains(subscriber) == false)
        {
            listeners.Add(subscriber);
        }
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                (IPEndPoint sender,string message) = await Receive();
                OnIncoming?.Invoke(sender, message);
            }
        });
    }

    public void Send(string message, IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Client.Send(datagram, datagram.Length, endpoint);
    }
    public async Task Broadcast(string message)
    {
        var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        await Task.WhenAll(listeners.Select(listeners => Client.SendAsync(datagram, datagram.Length, listeners)));
    }
    public async Task<(IPEndPoint Sender, string Message)> Receive()
    {
        var result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
        return (result.RemoteEndPoint, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length));
    }
}

class UdpListener
{
    UdpClient Client = new UdpClient();
    public event EventHandler<string>? OnIncoming;
    public UdpListener(string hostname, int port) 
    {
        Client.Connect(hostname, port);
        StartListening();
        Send("hello");
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        var datagram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Client.Send(datagram, datagram.Length);
    }
    private void StartListening()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                (IPEndPoint sender, string message) = await Receive();
                OnIncoming?.Invoke(sender, message);
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<(IPEndPoint Sender, string Message)> Receive()
    {
        var result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
        return (result.RemoteEndPoint, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on [Multicasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast), but honestly, just doing `await Task.WhenAll(server.SendAsync(dgram, clientEndpoint), server.SendAsync(dgram, client2Endpoint) ...);` is a lot easier and probably just as fast or marginally slower

Comment: Is [shared memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) an option? We use it to pass camera images between applications with very low latency.

Comment: You can use a named pipe instead of network options : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I have tried it, but only one client can get connected to a server in that case.

Comment: You need a different pipe name for each client.   You could create your own protocol where you have a main communication channel in UDP (or multicast) and then for each client send a command over TCP to open a new named pipe.